# How to customize expanded SearchView inside action bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, searchview

The default **SearchView** when expanded in the **ActionBar** looks like this image :

[image: Default SearchView]

I want to customize expanded **SearchView** similar to this image :

[image: Custom SearchView]

I am pretty new in Android Development. I would highly appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SearchView** for **Androidx** Package is composed by an **EditText** and some **AppCompatImageView** like the close icon and the search icon

To customize it you must access these views that I have talked about

for exmaple to change the background like the image you showed you need to create a shape  like belew :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <solid android:color="#02B15D" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#1A40FF" />
</shape>
```

this is how it's look the shape :

[image]

The shape above you must add it in the background of the **EditText**

To get this EditText is simple just use this in you `onCreateOptionMenu` :

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        EditText editText = (searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)); // get the EditText from it

        editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_search); // set the background to searchView
        
        // you can do more with the editText like textColor hint color ..... 
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

For customize  the search icon use this

```
AppCompatImageView searchIcon = searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
```

For the search button shown the the toolBar use this :

```
AppCompatImageView search_button = searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_button);
```

And finaly for the close button use this :

```
AppCompatImageView search_close_btn = searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
```

And this how the result looks like :

[image]

### UPDATE

To make the search icon visible at the left inside the SearchView you can add an icon to the EditText with this method :

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search,0,0,0);
```

If you use :

```
AppCompatImageView searchIcon =  searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon); searchIcon.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
```

you must add `searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);` but the icon becom visible outsid the shape please see the image below :

[image]

So if you want the icon inside the shape use the first method

Comment: I am able to customize the **EditText**. But cannot bring the Search icon (vector asset) on left side of expanded **SearchView**. Can you help with an example code with using a resource icon?

Code used:
`AppCompatImageView searchIcon =  searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
searchIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_search_24);`

Comment: @MayankLad please recheck my Answer I updated it